# Quick way to transfer "External Tool Configurations" from one Eclipse install to another?

Tags: eclipse, configuration, export, external

Is there a quick way to transfer the "External Tool Configurations" from one Eclipse install to another?

It doesn't seem to offer an import/export setting...

Answer (score 23, accepted):

I managed to copy my "External Tools Configurations" configuration (i.e. my Ant parameters and environment variables) from one workspace to another by copying *.launch* files in

```
<workspace>\.metadata\.plugins\org.eclipse.debug.core\.launches
```

Comment: Now, THIS is what I was hoping for! Awesome!!! And they're in XML-format, too, so I can even generate/update them with scripts. And if I can figure out how to make the .launches folder show up in the package explorer, I can put them under version control from inside Eclipse, too. Good stuff! Thanks!

Comment: To add this (or any other) folder to the Package Explorer go to *File -> New -> Project... -> General -> Project*. Pick a *Project name*. Uncheck *Use default location* and *Browse...* for the folder to show. *Finish*. Minor cosmetic issue: Eclipse will save a *.project* file in that folder...

Comment: Note: Doing this actually triggers a bug (or feature?) in Eclipse that results in a duplication of all Run-Configurations... Weird... Maybe Eclipse automatically also loads all .launch configs found inside any of the project folders?

Comment: Just tested this @MarkusA. You should just put your foo.launch in one of your projects and it magically appears in the dropdown menu

Comment: Since Eclipse loads `.launch` files found in a project, they probably *should not* be copied to the default `<workspace>/.../.launches` directory or else each External Tool will be shown twice in Eclipse.

Answer (score 16):

I found one more easy way , you can export the Launch Configurations from

```
File -> Export-> Run/Debug -> Launch Configurations
```

Comment: This should be the answer now.  Perhaps exporting wasn't a feature when the original question was posted, but I just successfully exported/imported a handful of external tool configurations from one system to another and it worked great.  Thanks Raaghu!

Answer (score 7):

1. Open the "External Tools Configurations" dialog.
2. Open the "Common" tab.
3. Select the "Shared file" radio button and enter a path for the location of the configuration file.

Eclipse will store your External Tools Configuration in the file you specified. You can use  this file in another instance of Eclipse to load the configuration. Add the 'your tool configuration'.launch file you created to the root of your destination project. The next time you refresh the project, Eclipse will load the configurations.

Comment: While this answer works, too, a new one by @foch just popped up that allows much better control over individual launch configurations!

Comment: with this approach We need to do for each launch configurations , a bit tedious when several launch configurations needs to be shared