# How to export an Eclipse builder (or package it) for Importing to other projects?

Tags: eclipse, export, builder

I've added a custom builder to my .project and it's now a separate tick box/ builder inside eclipse project properties. I'm looking for an easy way to import this to other projects.

Is there a way I can export the builder or package it for importing ?

Comment: Not clear ...you want to export the project ? .

Comment: If you go to a projects properties there's a tab for Builders, I'm trying to export one of these.

Answer (score 0):

If you've implemented the builder using the `New>Program` sequence adding the program you're calling in that manner, then the simplest solution is use the same specifications and add an external tool configuration with the same definition (you may need to delete the definition from the original project builder tab).

Once defined as an external tool, the tool can be imported using the import menu on the project builder tab.

Answer (score 0):

I use this method to create a builder template. Then import it and modify the parameters as needed. For reference, I'm using Neon.

Don't start at the builder. Start with the external tool configuration. External tool configurations can be exported and imported.

Detailing @Mark Walker's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27002628/5626983).

1. `Run > External Tools > External Tool Configurations > Program,
   right-click New (or New launch configuration button)`
2. Set up the tool parameters as you would the builder.
3. `Project > Properties > Builders > Import` - will now show you the
   builder to import.

This allows you to create a builder template that can be imported to any project within the workspace. I think the OP may have been interested in actually copying the builder to another workspace so I'm detailing that here.

Combining with answer: [Export the Launch Configurations](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42275984/5626983)

In source project:
`File > Export > Run/Debug > Launch Configurations > Program (> Select individual builders if needed) > Set export location > Finish`

In destination project:
`File > Import > Run/Debug > Launch Configurations > Select PARENT directory where you exported configurations > Select configurations > Finish`