# How do I show an arbitrary folder in the Eclipse Package Explorer?

Tags: eclipse, package-explorer

There are a couple of folders in different locations on my hard drive that contain resources I use a lot while coding (documentation, links, ...) but aren't really related to any specific one of my projects.

How can I have the Eclipse Package Explorer show such a folder that is not inside one of my existing projects?

*One potential use: [Quick way to transfer "External Tool Configurations" from one Eclipse install to another?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13713765/quick-way-to-transfer-external-tool-configurations-from-one-eclipse-install-to/26039528)                                (see comments to accepted answer...)*

Comment: Everything Package Explorer shows has to be in a project.

Comment: @greg-449 Yep. That's why I wrote "*existing* projects". :) But let me edit my answer to reflect this point.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since everything that the Package Explorer shows has to be in a project (as pointed out by *@greg-449*), one needs to create a dummy-project in the required location:

- Go to: *File* ⇒ *New* ⇒ *Project...* ⇒ *General* ⇒ *Project*
- Pick a *Project name*
- Uncheck *Use default location*
- *Browse...* for the folder to show
- Click *Finish*

Minor cosmetic issue: Eclipse will save a .project file in that folder...

*Aside:*

*To make this folder appear at the top of the list, one can give it a name like `_Documentation_` as Eclipse sorts the underscore before any letters.*